# How to clear the AutocompleteFilter search result programatically

Tags: android, google-places-api, autocompletefilter

I'm using an AutocompleteFilter view in my project and after the user clicks on the result I want to clear the search result in order to allow the user to write other places.

The intention is that my app will save in a list all selected places.

The solution that I have now is that I create another instance of the AutocompleteFilter, but I think there is a way but I can not find any documentation about it. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Post the code to show how you are doing it.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Do you mean how I create another instance or how I implemented the AutocompleteFilter?